# how to bind a error_handle in flask blueprint

Tags: flask

emmmmm. the problem is, i have three blueprint and use subdomian on there blueprint, such as  'www','admin','mobile',and register to app with url_prefix is default "/"

```
app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(mobile_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(front_blueprint)
```

when font_blueprint bind app_errorhandler(404).

the flask document:

app_errorhandler(code):

Like Flask.errorhandler() but for a blueprint. This handler is used for all requests, even if **outside** of the blueprint.

**outside of the blueprint.**   , so how can i bind a error_page with single blueprint

thx of help me

Answer (score 0):

You can [register a error handler to a blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Blueprint.errorhandler).

```
admin_blueprint = Blueprint("admin", __name__)

admin_blueprint.error_handler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    pass
```

Comment: Worth mentioning, that as of flask 3.0.0, particularly 404 is not handled by blueprints. From docs: "However, the blueprint cannot handle 404 routing errors because the 404 occurs at the routing level before the blueprint can be determined"
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/errorhandling/#handling